# Postgresql-Merge two databases into one

Tags: database, postgresql

The two databases have the same schema.
Is possible to merge databases like this?
And if yes can I do with more than two tables?
Probably I can do this with a python's script but if can I avoid that would be great.

```
Database 1

Student (IdStudent-Name-Age)
1;Peter;19
2;John;21
3;Anne;20

Course (IdCourse-Name)
1;Informatic
2;Biology

Student-Course (IdStudent-IdCourse)
1;1
2;1
3;2

Database 2

Student (IdStudent-Name-Age)
1;Christine;21
2;Mike;20
3;Frank;18
4;Katia;19

Course (IdCourse-Name)
1;Informatic
2;Biology
3;Chemistry

Student-Course (IdStudent-IdCourse)
1;3
2;2
3;3
4;1

Output:

Final Database 

Student (IdStudent-Name-Age)
1;Peter;19
2;John;21
3;Anne;20
4;Christine;21
5;Mike;20
6;Frank;18
7;Katia;19

Course (IdCourse-Name)
1;Informatic
2;Biology
3;Chemistry

Student-Course (IdStudent-IdCourse)
1;1
2;1
3;2
4;3
5;2
6;3
7;1
```

Comment: look at `dblink` and `FOREIGN TABLE` - both will help you (second preferred in most cases)

Comment: Also you need to add field new_id in old dbs and after  moving field to new store new_id (at least when it different from old)